# How to make activity blur, when fragment opened on button click

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity of product_description and there are images in it. If a user clicks any image, i'm showing it in a fragment of size 400x400. Fragment is the part of same activity. which is opened when image clicked and closed  when close button clicked.

Now i want to blur the activity when fragment is opened and remove the blur effect when fragment is closed.

**Below is my code of how i'm creating my fragment**

```
//set fragment into frameLayout
Fragment fragment = new textureImage_fragment();

//send extra args to fragment
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("imgUrl", imgUrl);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentManager fragmentManager = Product_description_Activity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout,fragment));


fragmentTransaction.commit();
//---- end fragment work -----
```

Comment: Blur is not natively supported by Android, so you'll need to take a screenshot of the View hierarchy and make it into a Bitmap, then blur the bitmap, then put the bitmap in an ImageView over your actual content.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce thanks for replying. But my view keeps on changing, it gets images and text from firebase which i show in image slider and text views.